# Angular directive ng-selected doesn't update model

Tags: angularjs

When using the angular directive ng-selected on an option, the bound model doesn't get updated until you manually change the selection.  Is this as designed?

http://jsfiddle.net/PqHsL/1/

```
<div ng-app ng-init="colors=['red', 'yellow', 'blue']">
  <select ng-model=selectedElement>
    <option ng-repeat="color in colors" value="{{color}}" ng-selected="$last">{{color}}</option>
  </select>

  selectedElement: {{ selectedElement }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it is working as designed.

I get the impression that ng-selected and ng-model don't play well together.  (Note that the [ng-selected API page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSelected) doesn't use ng-model in the example select list.)

Here are two ways to workaround this:

1. set the bound model in addition to setting ng-selected.  ng-init can also be used for this:

   `ng-init="colors=['red', 'yellow', 'blue']; selectedElement=colors[colors.length-1]"`
2. set the bound model, don't use ng-selected, use ng-options:
   `...ng-init as above...`
   `<select ng-model=selectedElement ng-options="color for color in colors">{{color}}</select>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/z6Vg8/).

Solution 1 has that weird "blank"/empty option, which disappears when you select something.  Solution 2 doesn't have the empty option, and is less verbose.  (So yeah, I like solution 2.)

I'm not sure what the use case is for ng-selected if we can set the model to preselect an option.  We can change the selection programatically later also -- see the ng-click in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/z6Vg8/).

Comment: I used #2, but, yes, had to set the model explicitly first.  thx.